# Globalize.addCultureInfo is not a function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, jquery-globalization

I am using the Globalize jQuery plugin to have globalization (correct number and date formats) on the client side in my MVC website. So I have downloaded that plugin and included the following javascript files after the validation js files themselves (I have tried putting the Globalize file before as well without any luck):

```
<script src="/Scripts/globalize.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.globalize.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/globalize/globalize.culture.da-DK.js"></script>
```

But when run the application, I get the error

> Globalize.addCultureInfo is not a function

I cannot figure out what the reason is

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize/blob/master/doc/migrating-from-0.x.md#globalizeaddcultureinfo) of the Globalize library itself, this function has been removed in the 1.x version. This function was exist in the versions 0.x

> This method is replaced by `Globalize.loadMessages( json )`. If you were using it for anything except message translations, you may also need to use `Globalize.load`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because the function addCulterInfo is not defined on globalize.js file.
I used somthing like that on one of my projects sometime ago. I hope it helps:

```
Globalize.addCultureInfo = function( cultureName, baseCultureName, info ) {
    var base = {},
            isNew = false;
    if ( typeof cultureName !== "string" ) {
            // cultureName argument is optional string. If not specified, assume info is first
            // and only argument. Specified info deep-extends current culture.
            info = cultureName;
            cultureName = this.culture().name;
            base = this.cultures[ cultureName ];
    } else if ( typeof baseCultureName !== "string" ) {
            // baseCultureName argument is optional string. If not specified, assume info is second
            // argument. Specified info deep-extends specified culture.
            // If specified culture does not exist, create by deep-extending default
            info = baseCultureName;
            isNew = ( this.cultures[ cultureName ] == null );
            base = this.cultures[ cultureName ] || this.cultures[ "default" ];
    } else {
            // cultureName and baseCultureName specified. Assume a new culture is being created
            // by deep-extending an specified base culture
            isNew = true;
            base = this.cultures[ baseCultureName ];
    }
    this.cultures[ cultureName ] = extend(true, {},
            base,
            info
    );
    // Make the standard calendar the current culture if it's a new culture
    if ( isNew ) {
            this.cultures[ cultureName ].calendar = this.cultures[ cultureName ].calendars.standard;
    }
};
```